# How to stop the console from flashing and disappearing

Tags: c#

İ have wrıtten my first code in C# as a console application in Visual Studio. However on running the code, the console just flashes and goes. How should i modify my code so as for the console to remain showing the message until i close it

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;


namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
   class Program
   {
      static void Main (string[] args)
      {
         System.Console.WriteLine("My name ıs Trevor");
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: add a System.Console.ReadLine(); after writeline to wait for the enter key before exiting your program

Comment: As a first project, you also need to change your `WriteLine` to `System.Console.WriteLine( "Hello World!" );`

Comment: Another problem is that the application throws an exception and disappears,  but only outside the IDE. A common cause is a missing reference, for example. In this case, you could try a `try/catch` along with `Console.ReadKey()`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are missing [Console.ReadKey()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.readkey.aspx):

```
namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
   class Program
   {
      static void Main (string[] args)
      {
         System.Console.WriteLine("My name ıs Trevor");
         Console.ReadKey();  // Add this line here.
      }
   }
}
```

Basically, you are missing a command to tell the console to wait for your input before closing itself.